# Using sonar.test.exclusions with Sonarqube 6.3

Tags: sonarqube

I'm currently evaluating Sonarqube 6.3 (a big upgrade from my current 5.5 instance) and I'm getting confused trying to work out the functionality of the **sonar.test.exclusions** setting.

There's this question: [Sonar Maven Plugin: How do I exclude test source directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048424/sonar-maven-plugin-how-do-i-exclude-test-source-directories/23531311#23531311) which seems to indicate that it is used to exclude test files from analysis (which is what I'm after - I don't want my sonar ruleset run over my unit tests). The documentation https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus also indicates that it is used to 'exclude unit test files' (perhaps this can be expanded upon to make it clearer?)

Thing is, when I add **sonar.test.exclusions** with a value of **/src/test/** and then run my analysis, I'm still getting code smells and the like being found for:

- Foo/src/test/java/foo/bar/BarTest.java
- Foo/src/test/java/lah/LahTest.java

etc.

When I use **sonar.exclusions** instead, they don't show up. Why is **sonar.test.exclusions** not doing what I expect?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all: if you have a Maven project, you should use the scanner for Maven (`mvn sonar:sonar`). It will simplify your configuration, and will automatically register src/test/java folder as a test directory.

Now if you want to do the configuration manually, or understand what is going on under the hood, here is the explanation: SonarQube scanner work with 2 sets of files, main and test. Main source files are configured using the property `sonar.sources`. Test source files are configured using `sonar.tests`.

On top of that, you can filter some content using the sonar.[test.]exclusions properties.

In you case your problem is that `Foo/src/test/java/foo/bar/BarTest.java` seems to be considered as a main source file. That's why `sonar.test.exclusions` has no effect.

Comment: ah. so if sonar.sources includes the test directories in the first place, it won't matter if sonar.test.exclusions if defined, because they'll be considered as source?

Comment: Don't you think renaming the property from 'sonar.exclusions' to 'sonar.source.exclusions' would help?

Comment: Maybe, the problem is that for backward compatibility reason we would have to keep both for a very long time...

Comment: Is the meaning of and difference between `sonar.exclusions` and `sonar.test.exclusions` documented anywhere? (https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/ says nothing useful about this).

Answer (score 4):

Using maven with verfication goal (*mvn clean verify sonar:sonar install*), I have used this configuration without problems:

```
...
<properties>
    ....
    <sonar.exclusions>
        **/generated/**/*,
        **/model/**/*
    </sonar.exclusions>
    <sonar.test.exclusions>
        src/test/**/*
    </sonar.test.exclusions>
    ....
    <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
    <sonar.coverage.exclusions>
        **/generated/**/*,
        **/model/**/*
    </sonar.coverage.exclusions>
    <jacoco.version>0.7.5.201505241946</jacoco.version>
    ....
</properties>
....
```

Coverage exclusion configuration, inside properties (up) and jacoco plugin configuracion:

```
.....
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-unit-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>target/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                        <outputDirectory>target/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
....
```

Comment: +1 for <sonar.exclusions>
        **/generated/**/*,
        **/model/**/*
    </sonar.exclusions>

Answer (score 0):

### What is Analysis Scopes?

> There are many cases where you do not want to analyze every aspect of
> every source file in your project.
>
> For example:
>
> Your project may
> contain generated code, source code from libraries, or intentionally
> duplicated code.
> In such cases, it makes sense to skip some or all
> aspects of analysis for these files, thus removing noise and allowing
> you to focus on the issues that really matter. [[1](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarcloud/advanced-setup/analysis-scope/)]

---

### What's relation of `sonar.test.exclusions` with Reporting?

The `sonar.test.exclusions` defines the **exclusion scope for analysis of test code and has nothing to do with the reporting.**

> The test scope parameters (`source.tests` , `sonar.test.exclusion`, and `sonar.test.inclusion`) do not have anything to do with setting up test coverage reporting [[1](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarcloud/advanced-setup/analysis-scope/)].

---

### What's relation of `sonar.coverage.exclusions` with Reporting?

You can prevent specific files or directories from being taken into account **when code coverage is reported**. **It is related to both the analysis and reporting.**

> The parameter `sonar.coverage.exclusions` is directly related to test coverage reporting [[1](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarcloud/advanced-setup/analysis-scope/)].